# No more worries that you'll miss

Tags: word-usage

Can I use the construction "No more worries" in the meaning like "you don't need to worry any more that something will go wrong."

Here is the full context
"No more worries that you’ll miss on our new pictures! We'll notify you as soon as new images come in."

Answer (score -1):

No it is not correct in terms of grammar. It loses continuity after `worries`. Moreover, if we break down the sentence it's like a person named `Nomore` is worried that another person is going to miss those new pictures. That's not what you meant.

A better version would be `Don't worry about missing out our new pictures`.